# Subassembly identification, including a hotel sign

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I got these assemblies and I am trying to figure out if they are MOCs or part of a set or sets. I have identified the red sub-assembly as set 60182 Pickup and Caravan.

The hotel sign looks like the...

What about the rest? I think I have at least parts from 4 sets?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hotel part is from [10182-1: Cafe Corner](https://brickset.com/sets/10182-1/Cafe-Corner),

The Olive Green canoes come from [70623-1: Destiny's Shadow](https://brickset.com/sets/70623-1/Destiny-s-Shadow)

The brown assemblies  on the lower right second picture are from [7662-1: Trade Federation MTT](https://brickset.com/sets/7662-1/Trade-Federation-MTT)

-see step 54 on page 61 https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4515434.pdf

and parts from [10696-1: Medium Creative Brick Box](https://brickset.com/sets/10696-1/Medium-Creative-Brick-Box) ( crocodile)

also there is a Smurf and a Playmobil figure

Comment: If there is a full 10182 in there, you have struck gold (depending on how much you paid). Even used, those go for big bucks on the second-hand market (think $500+).

Comment: I am still searching what goes where from the pile, but it looks I prety much got the hotel sign.  probably with broken neons too.

Comment: @syberion  Thank you Sir.

Comment: Can you recognize the two brown rooftop like assemblies to the lower right of the last pic?

Comment: You have more than the hotel sign - that yellow and white canopy build is also from 10182.

Comment: @Phil B.  True and correct on the yellow/white canopy. Set is about 2200 pieces.  I probably got about 300 of them.  Great set though.  Thanks for you help.